# The difference between Public Sub and Private Sub

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if you could say what is the difference between these two subs:

```
Public Sub name ()
.
.
End Sub
```

and this :

```
Private Sub name ()
.
.
End Sub
```

in VB.Net after creating new procedures the default is Public but in VB6, the programmer can choose between 2 options I listed.

Comment: This is really basic stuff. Please read some tutorials or start directly with the VB.NET references https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Access Levels in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx)

This is basic stuff about the language, make sure you read the other topics listed on the left on that page.

Answer (score 0):

The public sub is accessible to other forms in your project. You can call them with `<form name>.<function name>(parameters)` (e.g. `Form1.name(mystuff.tostring())`). Private subs, on the other hand, are only accessible from their own class, usually the form.